Spring(Legacy Project) : Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ProjectName'. javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor
error
Has anyone faced this error?
someone suspected this error caused from java path setting .
In my descktop i have jdk 11 and jdk 17.
this project is made based on jdk 11 so i created a system variable JAVA_HOME and Path for it.
In "Properties" tap of the project i made sure the jdk-11 is the JRE System Library.
I reinstalled jdk 11, tried to add javax annotation api in Maven dependencies,
But nothing worked.
I guess the point this project was directly compressed into zip file may be a problem? Is that right?
Please i hope you guys can guide me from this pit with darkness
